# How to find parameter definitions with (python3) help()

Tags: python

So when I use help() to preform a quick search of a package's content - for example - "tkinter.Button" it shows me everything about Button. Although, what I'm interested in are the STANDARD OPTIONS and WIDGET-SPECIFIC OPTIONS. What command line would I need to type in so the definitions for these options will be displayed instead of just the names. I've had this question for a while now but haven't been able to figure it out

P.S. pretty sure this is a problem that is tkinter docs specific but nonetheless if anyone knows the syntax to answer the problem id be pleased

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'standard' vs 'widget-specific'? Do you mean what attributes and methods `Button` specifically adds over its direct ancestor? As far as I know there's no standard way to get that information - why not rely on the documentation instead? https://tkdocs.com/shipman/button.html

Comment: The definitive list of options is in the tcl/tk man pages. They require just a very simple mental translation from tcl to python. http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6.11/TkCmd/contents.htm